# "Transaction Log for database is full" SQL error

Tags: sql, database, db2

I am trying to insert some values into an SQL database, but continuously receiving an error that "Transaction Log for database is full".

I checked it online and some people have suggested to commit work more frequently. I have done than with no changes.

I don't have authorization to change database server. Is this problem client-side or due to server? If due to client, what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a server side issue, you should forward the messages to the DBA team.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably getting the error code SQL0964, aren't you?

Probably you execute your DML sentences when there is a lot of activity in the database, and you got this message because your sentences overpassed the log size limit.

The concurrent transactions have used all the available logs (primary and secondary) and your sentences cannot be written in the logs.

Also, if the database has archive log method, probably the file system is full and the database cannot archive the active logs, blocking you to write your sentences in the transaction logs.

Any of these situations can be solved by your DBA team. You can only change the way you insert the rows by doing commit more frequently (if currently a commit is each 500 rows, try a commit each 100 rows, something like that)

For more information about the problem: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00964c.html