# "The transaction log for database is full due to 'LOG_BACKUP'" in a shared host

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

I have an Asp.Net MVC 5 website with EntityFramework codefirst approach in a shared hosting plan. It uses the open source [WebbsitePanel](http://www.websitepanel.net/) for control panel and its SQL Server panel is somewhat limited. Today when I wanted to edit the database, I encountered this error:

```
The transaction log for database 'db_name' is full due to 'LOG_BACKUP'
```

I searched around and found a lot of related answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025344/transaction-log-for-database-is-full-sql-error) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975905/potential-causes-and-solutions-for-the-transaction-log-in-database-being-full) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56628/how-do-you-clear-the-sql-server-transaction-log) but the problem is they suggest running a query on the database. I tried running

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE db_name SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;");
```

with the visual studio (on the `HomeController`) but I get the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: ALTER DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction.
```

How can I solve my problem? Should I contact the support team (which is a little poor for my host) or can I solve this myself?

Comment: Execute the ALTER without a transaction.

Comment: @usr How would I do that?

Comment: Its a database issue, shrinking the database could work. Ask a DBA to help you on this.

Comment: You must have opened a transaction somehow. I don't know, maybe EF does that automatically. You'd need to do some research on EF and transaction. Or, execute this from SSMS. Or, use raw ADO.NET. Probably your hoster won't allow that statement anyway and they need to issue log backups more frequently.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Call your hosting company and either have them set up regular log backups or set the recovery model to simple. I'm sure you know what informs the choice, but I'll be explicit anyway. Set the recovery model to full if you need the ability to restore to an arbitrary point in time. Either way the database is misconfigured as is.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to do this myself but contacted them too and they've set up the recovery and ran a `shrink` on the DB. Also, I didn't need the recovery so I told them to set it to `SIMPLE` mode.

Comment: This [MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/view-or-change-the-recovery-model-of-a-database-sql-server) explains how to set the recovery model to simple !

Answer (score 251):

In Addition to Ben's Answer, You can try Below Queries as per your need

```
USE {database-name};  
GO  
-- Truncate the log by changing the database recovery model to SIMPLE.  
ALTER DATABASE {database-name}
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;  
GO  
-- Shrink the truncated log file to 1 MB.  
DBCC SHRINKFILE ({database-file-name}, 1);  
GO  
-- Reset the database recovery model.  
ALTER DATABASE {database-name}
SET RECOVERY FULL;  
GO
```

**Update** Credit **@cema-sp**

To find database file names use below query

```
select * from sys.database_files;
```

Comment: Additional: to find {database-file-name}: `select * from sys.database_files;`

Comment: Is there a way this can be done on a sql server instance basis (so that it applies for all DBs) ?

Comment: I can confirm this works a treat. Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks @Mohit Dharmadhikari; I tried many other things including allocating more disk space, and increasing the log file size, yet nothing worked until I shrunk the existing Log file first.

Comment: [MS Docs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#b-shrinking-a-log-file-to-a-specified-target-size)

Comment: I believe {database-file-name} would equate to the `name` column, for the row of the log, from this query: `select * from sys.database_files`

Comment: This answer works but I have been warned that it will interfere with RDS incremental (every-5-min) backups, which effectively apply the transaction log in sequence to the last full backup -- so when you loose the log you might not be able to restore your db properly

Comment: It works well, funny that accepted answer gets +45, if I answered the question like "Please contact your administrator if problem is not resolved please contact your vendor if it still exists maybe it is your problem". I am sure I would be banned :D

Comment: It should be worth noting that you need to run a full backup after switching the recovery model from SIMPLE back to FULL. [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/view-or-change-the-recovery-model-of-a-database-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#FollowUp).

Answer (score 32):

Occasionally when a disk runs out of space, the message "transaction log for database XXXXXXXXXX is full due to 'LOG_BACKUP'" will be returned when an update SQL statement fails.
Check your diskspace :)

Answer (score 13):

This can also happen when the log file is restricted in size.

Right click database in Object Explorer

Select Properties

Select Files

On the log line, click the ellipsis in the Autogrowth / Maxsize column

Change/verify Maximum File Size is Unlimited.

[image]

After chaning to unlimited, database came back to life.

Comment: I tried this but never changes to unlimited. How can I do to add another log file?

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga This won't change anything. Unlimited is 2TB.

Answer (score 10):

This error occurs because the transaction log becomes full due to LOG_BACKUP. Therefore, you can’t perform any action on this database, and In this case, the SQL Server Database Engine will raise a 9002 error.

To solve this issue you should do the following

- Take a Full database backup.
- Shrink the log file to reduce the physical file size.
- Create a LOG_BACKUP.
- Create a LOG_BACKUP Maintenance Plan to take backup logs frequently.

I wrote an article with all details regarding this error and how to solve it at [The transaction log for database ‘SharePoint_Config’ is full due to LOG_BACKUP](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/04/26/the-transaction-log-for-database-sharepoint_config-is-full-due-to-log_backup/)

Comment: Posting the error message as your answer isn't very helpful at all. Link-only answers are also frowned upon on StackOverflow. You should extract the relevant text from the link and quote it here. This is especially important in case the link dies in the future, as all links inevitably do.

Comment: This was the cause for me. The previous DBA had put a limit on the log file size.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error but from a backend job (SSIS job).  Upon checking the database's Log file growth setting, the log file was limited growth of 1GB.  So what happened is when the job ran and it asked SQL server to allocate more log space, but the growth limit of the log declined caused the job to failed.  I modified the log growth and set it to grow by 50MB and Unlimited Growth and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

#### Rescue Method

Run the query to get the database file name:

```
select * from sys.database_files;
```

Afterward, run this query:

```sql
USE {database-name};  GO  -- Truncate the log by changing the database recovery model to SIMPLE.  ALTER DATABASE {database-name}SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;  GO  -- Shrink the truncated log file to 1 MB.  DBCC SHRINKFILE ({database-file-name}, 1);  GO  -- Reset the database recovery model.  
ALTER DATABASE {database-name}
SET RECOVERY FULL;  
GO
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?