# The transaction log for database 'test' is full due to 'LOG_BACKUP'. and free space issue with C Drive

Tags: sql-server

I am using MSSQL for storing data.When I tried to delete the data in a table, it shows an error

> The transaction log for database 'test' is full due to 'LOG_BACKUP'.

Also, I have checked the size of C drive, and it almost full now, before doing this delete operation, the free space was 10GB.

When I searched for the error, I found that backing up the transaction log will resolve the issue.I did the same and still, C drive remains full.

What I can do to resolve the issue?

Comment: Have a look here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73436/transaction-log-full-due-to-log-backup or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228688/the-transaction-log-for-database-is-full-due-to-log-backup-in-a-shared-host/21235001

Comment: Go to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL<your version>\MSSQL\Log` and delete .LDF file which is large. These are log files and can be removed without harming system.

Comment: Transaction logs are a crucial part of SQL Server. Do not try to delete them.

Comment: Is there any problem, if I shrink instead of deleting them as per sepupic comments

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As per the comments, I have shrunk the transaction log file, it freed up around 13GB. Since the recovery model of my database is Full, first I have taken a backup of transaction logs and then change the recovery model of my database to Simple. After that, I have shrunk my log files and again set back to Full.

```
 ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
    SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
    GO
    DBCC SHRINKFILE (AdventureWorks2012_log, 1)
    GO
    ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
    SET RECOVERY FULL
```

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3311/how-to-shrink-the-transaction-log/

Thanks, @sepupic, for the very accurate approach you have mentioned in the post. After cleaned up space, I have deleted the records in small batches as per the comments of @Pedro Martins.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) That is the first working answer I found this past hour!

Comment: confirmo, funciono 10 puntos

Comment: file path:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA

Answer (score 3):

Your database is in `FULL` recovery model. Your `log` is full because you don't take regular log backups, and this is the only thing that clears the log in `full` recovery model. So what you need now is `log backup`.
This will `truncate` your log. Log truncation does not change log size but it permits the log to be reused.

> When I searched for the error, I found that backing up the transaction
>   log will resolve the issue.I did the same and still, C drive remains
>   full.

As I said, log truncation just permits to log to be overwritten, it does not change its size.

What is your actual `ldf` and `mdf` file sizes? If your log is bigger than your data file it means that your backup strategy is wrong and you need to `shrink` log file to appropriate size.

You also need to plan `regular log backups` or valuate whether `simple` recovery model is better for you.

Comment: I read the post which Valerica mentioned in the above comment.it is telling like The Shrink operation effects on SQL Server Performance during executing shrink command. it also causes index fragmentation and can slow the performance of queries that search a range of the index.Is it true?Is shrinking is a recommended way to clean up the space?

Comment: @Kesiya Abraham >>>it also causes index fragmentation <<< What are you talking about??? **Log** shrinking has nothing to do with index fragmentation. It's not resource intensive either. All it does it gives the space back to OS if it's possible (if active VLFs are not at the end of log space), if it's not possible it just does nothing

Comment: @Kesiya Abraham What you described is **DATA** file shrink, when the data is moved from the end of the file to its beginning. What I described is **LOG** shrinking, and there is NO data move withing log file, it's just impossible

Comment: Thanks sepupic..it was my mistake and thought that shrinking means not only the log files but also the data files...this will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Check the database recovery model. It might be set to FULL. You can try to change to SIMPLE.

More info:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/view-or-change-the-recovery-model-of-a-database-sql-server
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server

If you don't want to change the recovery model, try delete your data in small batches, example:

```
DELETE TOP (1000) FROM table WHERE condition;
GO
```

#### Edit:

To compact your databases right now you can shink the log. You'll get best results if you change the database recovery model to SIMPLE.

```
USE [master];
GO

-- 1) Compacts all the databases in database server instance
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (''?'' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY);DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (''?'' , 0);'
GO

-- 2) Compacts all the databases in database server instance that matches certain database name
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'DBCC SHRINKDATABASE ('+ name +', 0, TRUNCATEONLY);DBCC SHRINKDATABASE ('+ name +', 0);'
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE name LIKE '%database_name%'
    ORDER BY name ASC;
EXEC (@SQL);
GO
```

Comment: To delete the data I can use this information.My problem is C drive is full now.I think it happened while I tried to delete whole data at the same time and it made a large transaction log.So how can I delete this transaction log

Comment: Try this:

USE [master];
GO

-- 1) Compacts all the databases in database server instance
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (''?'' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY);DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (''?'' , 0);'
GO

Comment: Thanks Pedro..will try this one too