# The transaction log for database is full due to 'log_backup' / (Log)LDF file 4 times bigger than (Data)MDF

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transaction-log

Of course I found many posts to the problem of "log_backup". But my question is now: what is the right / correct / professional way to handle this kind of problem?

My database file is approx 20GB, the transaction log-file is 100 GB (4 times bigger). I'm sure that I do not need all this backup transactions. So what's the right way to shrink the log file to approx 20GB?

Have I just to follow [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48885256/the-transaction-log-for-database-test-is-full-due-to-log-backup-and-free-sp) and set recovery mode to simple, shrink and then to do a full backup? Or would you suggest another solution, like backup the log file and start a new one? (I'm not sure, if this is possible?!)

Comment: The longer term answer to "what is the right / correct / professional way to handle this kind of problem" depends on your requirements. Primarily: Do you need point in time restore? (being able to restore your DB to a particular point in time

Answer (score 0):

You are basically answering your own question, all you need to do is choose one option.

I am guessing your recovery model is full: this means that ALL your transactions will be written to the log file for 'point in time restore'. That is why your log file is so big and unless you:

- back it up and shrink the log file
- change recovery model to simple and shrink the log file

it will stay that way.

The 2 solutions are more or less equivalent. There is a small risk in the latter option of having no way to do a point in time restore if your server crashes right after you change the recovery model and shrink the file, but I am guessing that is a 0,(0)1 possibility and not an issue since you backups are not properly set up.

In either situation, if you decide to leave your recovery model set to full make sure you include the log in some sort of a regular backup, otherwise you (or somebody else) are going to have this problem again somewhere in the future.